# How to trigger Messages at specific times?

Tags: apache-camel

We have a DB table where every row has a text message and a timestamp. E.g.

Mesg1 09:00

Mesg2 09:01

Mesg3 09:15

Mesg4 09:20

The timings are not at a fixed interval. It is uneven. We would like to read the table as a Source and send the Messages to a Target at the configured timestamps. Components like Quartz do not allow configuring uneven trigger times.

Is there a common pattern that can be followed for such a use case?

Regards,
Yash

Answer (score 0):

Use [camel cron](https://camel.apache.org/components/3.20.x/cron-component.html) component for the trigger events.

```
from("cron:tab?schedule=0/1+*+*+*+*+?")
.setBody().constant("event")
.log("${body}");
```

The schedule expression 0/3+10+*+*+*+? can be also written as 0/3 10 * * * ? and triggers an event every three seconds only in the tenth minute of each hour.

Comment: I have stated that the timings are uneven. There is no fixed interval and it is not random. The time of each even is individually fixed.